# Which process scheduling algorithm is used by Linux?

Tags: linux, process, scheduling

The Linux operating system switches between running processes to enable multi-tasking.

What algorithm is used to determine when to suspend the execution of the currently running process and which process should run next?

Answer (score 7):

In newer kernels, the Completely Fair Scheduler is used (it replaces the O(1) scheduler of older kernels).

The CFS stores the planned task in a red-black tree and uses the spent CPU time amount for the process has run as a key. This allows the scheduler to pick the process with the least amount of run-time (which is stored in the left-mode node of the tree) efficiently.

Once the task is about to be run, it is removed from the tree, and then when it runs, it is re-added with the new CPU time used.

Processes that are "sleeping" for a long time will automatically get a priority boost, since they don't have a large spent CPU time.

Therefore, it is "fair", since processes that are sleeping get as much CPU time as processes that are constantly running

Comment: Just an addition, here's the link of CFS source code in lxr, in case anyone wants to have a look on its actual implementation: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c